# How can I find out what file mode VSCode is using for an open file?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was trying to get [yapf](https://github.com/google/yapf) configured for a Python project, and so I created a `.style.yapf` file, which VSCode did not recognize by its extension.  I thought it was in TOML format, but when I changed the file association for `.style.yapf` to `TOML`, the parser shows an error (because values aren't quoted).  So I tried changing the name of the file (not really a solution, because the tool is looking for a file with that name), and found that if I change it to a name ending in `.cfg`, VSCode seems to parse and highlight it appropriately.  Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be anything in the list of file associations corresponding to this file mode.

I expected to find a `cfg` mode in the file associations list, but there wasn't an entry with that name, nor was there an entry that used the same gear icon displayed next to the open file name in its tab (which I have been assuming is an indicator of the mode that VSCode is using to display and format the file).

Is there any way for me to get VSCode to tell me what the current file mode is for an open file?  Or give me a list of the default associations?

I'm more interested in understanding the tools in general than solving the one minor annoyance that sparked the question, but I'll settle for a solution to that problem, too.

---

Edit:  Here's the content of the `.style.yapf` file in question:

```
[style]
based_on_style = google
```

If I rename the file to `.yapf.cfg` (or any other name ending in `.cfg`, I believe), it gets handled properly, but all of the file associations I've tried (including `ini`, `Properties`, and `TOML`) indicate an error because there are no quotes around `google`.

Comment: it look more like `ini` files, and that has a default languageID, change the setting `files.associations`

Comment: Use `properties` language for `.cfg` like syntax or `ini` language is also a close match.
`"files.associations": { "*.yapf": "properties" }`
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_changing-the-language-for-the-selected-file

Comment: Thanks, @rioV8 & @CS, but neither `ini` nor `Properties` results in error-free parsing of the file in question.  It seems like `.cfg` files get some special treatment, and it's hidden…